# Azure DevOps Service Connection - Azure Resource Manager using service principal (manual) with Key Vault Secret values

Tags: azure-devops, serviceconnection

I have created Azure Key Vault and then created secret with Service Principal Client Secret ID value into it. Next, I’m trying to create Azure Resource Manager Service Connection (Manual Type) in Azure DevOps. In that I want to read the Client Secret Value from Azure Key Vault.

Is it possible to create ARM Service Connection by reading the Client Secret Value from Azure Key Vault in Azure DevOps?

Comment: There's no option for that in Azure DevOps to my knowledge. You have to enter the secret value. I can see where this adds value, though (not having your service connections blow up when secrets expire).

Answer (score 0):

While creation of Service Connection with Azure Resource Manager using service principal (manual), there is no option to reference the Service principal key from Key Vault Secrets. We need to manually enter the Service principal key.

[image]